# Set max height to list in fluid width content

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, fluid-layout

I have the following http://jsfiddle.net/4G33W/1/

This is fluid as it is and works fine, but when more items are added to the list in the #commentWrapper, it breaks the layout as it pushes the whole thing "downwards".

To test copy some more `<li>test</li>` items, and you will see what i mean.
I want the input box to stay at the bottom (as it is atm) and when the list becomes long enough and reaches it, the list should go to "overflow-x:auto" mode. I can't use a fixed height as it will break the "fluidness" of the whole thing, or at least the ways i tried didn't seem to work.

Any css/html solution here? Should I turn to javascript for the solution? I'm using jquery as well, just in case any answer has javascript included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with pure css in this case. Applying these rules to the `#commentWrapper` element will do the trick:

```
#commentWrapper {
    width: 17%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4G33W/2/

Comment: Glad I could help. Also @Willian Duarte made some very good points. I can confirm that this solution works on IE8+ and all other major browsers. (IE7 an below versions have less than 5% global usage and are obsolete, so I would discourage support for them).

Answer (score 2):

@Bogdan solution works because "height: 100%;" works when "position: absolute;" is setted. Beware the layout you need to build and the browsers you need to support.

And look at [can i use](http://caniuse.com) for [box-sizing](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) support.